# Can I input a variable that can input only a name with space?

Tags: python

I am using python 3.6.5
I want to input a variable which can take in name of the person with space. This is my code for it right now:

```
def addition():
    with open('Directory.csv','a',newline='') as file:
        w=csv.writer(file,delimiter=',')
        def names():
            name=input('Enter Name     :')
            n=0
            for i in name:
                if i.isalpha() or i.isspace():
                    n+=0
                else:
                    n+=1
            if n==0:
                return name
            else:
                print('Error')
            return names()
        name=names()
```

But when I press enter without any value inputted, it still accepts it:

```
Enter Value of k     :     2
Enter Name     :
Enter Year of Birth     :
```

What should be my code to correct this?

Comment: I'd suggest removing the irrelevant portions. We don't need to see your I/O, and your printed output doesn't match your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: @Matthias. While that's good advice, it's completely irrelevant to the actual question.

Comment: Yes! Thank You. Found a solution through that using length of string inputted.

Comment: @IvinGeorgi. I've added a regex solution too

Comment: You might find the answer to the question [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem here is that the loop `for i in name:` won't run if `name` is empty, leaving `n` at zero. The least invasive way to fix this is to check in the subsequent `if`:

```
if name and n == 0:
```

There are other improvements I'd recommend, starting with removing the recursive call in favor of a loop. A user could trigger a stack overflow by typing in bad characters enough times.

Rather than counting bad characters, you can break out of the loop early. This removes your dependence on `n` entirely:

```
def names():
    while True:
        name = input('Enter Name: ')
        if name:
            for i in name:
                if not i.isalpha() or not i.isspace():
                    break
            else:
                return name
        print('Error')
```

The `else` clause here is correctly matched to the `for` loop. It's a neat python trick for running code only if the loop didn't `break`.

There are less manual ways to check that a string contains only letters and spaces. The most popular likely being regular expressions, which are supported by the standard library. This would be a simple regex:

```
import re

...

name_pattern = re.compile('[a-zA-Z ]+')

...

def names():
    while True:
        name = input('Enter Name: ').strip()
        if name_pattern.fullmatch(name):
            return name
        print('Error')
```

Comment: This is exactly what was needed for the code. Thank you so much